# Check pairs of lottery numbers from archive

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2014-express

I'm trying to find best possible solution to check pairs concerning to my national lottery. They draw six numbers. I have a database with all the previous drawings. The question is what is the most efficient table structure and the way of checking lottery number pairs'?

This is how my table looks:

```
year (float)    
date (nvarchar)    
draw (float)    
no1 (smallint)    
no2 (smallint)    
no3 (smallint)    
no4 (smallint)    
no5 (smallint)    
no6 (smallint)
```

I use this query to find a pair of numbers:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM archive
WHERE '1' IN (no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6) AND '36' IN (no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6)
```

I got the result 10 (the pair was draw out 10 times).

If I want to check the next pair, for example 1 and 37, I need to use the query again but with other numbers

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM archive
WHERE '1' IN (no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6) AND '37' IN (no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6)
```

I got the result 13 (the pair was draw out 13 times)

Is there a SQL query (or some better solution) that can automatically check pairs in the number range from 1 to 90; example:

```
Pair 1 and 2
Pair 1 and 3
Pair 1 and 4
.
.
```

all the way up to pair 89 and 90?

Comment: Please tell me you are not doing this to try and predict future draws!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a little through the lines a little here, but a Tally seems to be the best choice here:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (90) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Draws,
       T1.I AS Number1,
       T2.I AS Number2
FROM dbo.Archive S
     CROSS JOIN Tally T1
     JOIN Tally T2 ON T1.I < T2.I
WHERE T1.I IN (no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6)
  AND T2.I IN (no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6)
GROUP BY T1.I, T2.I;
```

Answer (score 0):

With this table:
id, tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4

and with this code, you can find the occurrences:

--alter table [BASE1].[dbo].[MiBase.2sep22] add idserie int identity(1,1)

--inicio all--
Declare @tblConteos TABLE(Veces int, Nros varchar(30), Orden varchar(10))

/* Conocer Parejas*/
;WITH SEMILLA AS (Select [idserie] as Serie, Numero from [BASE1].[dbo].[MiBase.2sep22]
UNPIVOT(Numero FOR Nros in (N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6)) as Num)
, SERIES2 AS (Select TOP 100 PERCENT S1.Serie, S1.Numero as Numero1, S2.Numero as Numero2
FROM SEMILLA AS S1
CROSS JOIN
SEMILLA AS S2
WHERE S2.Serie = S1.Serie AND S2.Numero <> S1.Numero AND S2.Numero > S1.Numero
ORDER BY S1.Numero)
insert into @tblConteos
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Serie)) AS Veces, Numero1 + ',' + Numero2 as Parejas, 'Parejas'
FROM SERIES2
GROUP BY Numero1, Numero2
HAViNG COUNT(DISTINCT(Serie))>1

SELECT TOP 20 Veces, Nros FROM @tblConteos where orden = 'PAREJAS' ORDER BY Veces DESC

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer using the formatting possibilties we provide in order to make it more readble. Also, please note, that this is the English only version of the side, regarding your comments, variable names etc.